# KendoUI dropdown filter doesn't work with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I try to add the filter to KendoUI dropdown list and It seems like not working. filter works fine without the angular. But when I add that to with angular it doesn't show the type filter inside the dropdown. I used the same example which is in the official website.

```html
<div ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <h4 style="padding-top: 2em;">Remote data</h4>
    <select kendo-drop-down-list
            k-data-text-field="'ProductName'"
            k-data-value-field="'ProductID'"
            k-data-source="productsDataSource"
            style="width: 100%">
    </select>
<div>
```

Controller

```js
angular.module('myApp', ["kendo.directives"])
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.productsDataSource = {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        filter: "startswith",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",          
            }
        }
    };    
}]);
```

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IshanFx/ug3d61cs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing your "filter" property incorrectly. Please see the [demo guide](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering).

The filter property should be in the kendo-drop-down-list element but since you are not using the kendo-drop-down-list as a tag and just using it as a property of the select element you need to add the filter property in the element tag as well. See below:

```html
<select kendo-drop-down-list
    k-data-text-field="'ProductName'"
    k-data-value-field="'ProductID'"
    k-data-source="productsDataSource"
    filter="'startsWith'"
    style="width: 100%"></select>
<div>
```

and of course remove your filter property from your angular module

```js
angular.module('myApp', ["kendo.directives"])
    .controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.productsDataSource = {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                    }
                }
            };
        }]);
```

See the [JSFilddle fork of your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xobLa38/)